# How to transform 'b' div while mouse is hover 'a' or 'c'?

Tags: html, css, selector

I don't know which selector I should use. This is my code.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    .button:nth-child(2) {
      transform: scale(1.2);
    }
    
    .button:hover:not(:nth-child(2))~.button:nth-child(2) {
      transform: scale(1);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="button">gallery</div>
    <div class="button">Main</div>
    <div class="button">XYZ</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to scale down the middle div while the mouse is `:hover` different div in the same parent. My code works well for 'a' div but it doesnt work for 'c'. Could someone help me?

Comment: share your code and we'll see what you are doing wrong to select and edit the element

Comment: You cannot achieve it with `~`. It's only applied to downward siblings (elements below that hovering element). In your case, `a` can apply styles to `b`, but `c` cannot apply styles to `b` because `c` is a downward sibling of `b`

Comment: you can make a  on mouse enter function call and animate in the function

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with the general sibling combinator as it only selects siblings of the second element that follow after the first element (in your case the button 2nd child only comes after the first button which is why your selector only works for the first button and not the third one).

Instead you can add the hover to the parent and cancel when the second child is hovered:

```css
.button:nth-child(2),
.menu:hover .button:nth-child(2):hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.menu:hover .button:nth-child(2) {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="button">gallery</div>
  <div class="button">Main</div>
  <div class="button">XYZ</div>
</div>
```

If you cannot put the hover on the parent due to other child elements that you don't want hovered, then you will need to use javascript